# Difference between consecutive rows using an if statement but condition has length > 1

Tags: r, if-statement

I have seen similar questions to mine but could not find the way to solve it in this specific case.

I am trying to do the difference between values from two consecutive rows when the value in another column is negative. If not, I want to copy the value from another column.

```
    symbol      Strt        End         len    Overlap
121 TPTE2P4     26508213    26579690    1605    153795
46  CYCSP49     26549425    26549743    319     -30265
116 SLC25A15P1  26586642    26591601    342      36899
84  PARP4P1     26594851    26634652    2337      3250
```

So with the date from above,
I am trying to do the difference between values from two consecutive rows (End of the current row -Start from the previous row) when the value in `Overlap` column is negative. If not, I want to copy the value from `len`. I should expect these results in the column `len_no_overlap`:

```
    symbol      Strt        End         len    Overlap  len_no_overlap
121 TPTE2P4     26508213    26579690    1605    153795       1605
46  CYCSP49     26549425    26549743     319    -30265    **41530**
116 SLC25A15P1  26586642    26591601     342     36899        342
84  PARP4P1     26594851    26634652    2337      3250       2337
```

So in this case, only in the second row the `Overlap` is negative, and the `len_no_overlap` value comes from `26549743-26508213`.

I have written the code as follows but can not vectorise it to work

```
if (DPM_356_out_High_loss$Overlap < 0) {
   DPM_356_out_High_loss$len_no_overlap <- c(NA, tail(DPM_356_out_High_loss$End, -1)      head(DPM_356_out_High_loss$Strt, -1))
   } else {
       DPM_356_out_High_loss$len_no_overlap <- DPM_356_out_High_loss$len
   }
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done without loops, just fully vectorized code.

1. First, create the new column by assigning the entire old column to it, not caring to know if the values in `Overlap` are negative.
2. Then get indices to the negative values in `Overlap`.
3. Finally, compute the differences in one instruction.

The code becomes the following.

```
DPM_356_out_High_loss$len_no_overlap <- DPM_356_out_High_loss$len
inx <- which(DPM_356_out_High_loss$Overlap < 0)

DPM_356_out_High_loss$len_no_overlap[inx] <- DPM_356_out_High_loss$End[inx] - DPM_356_out_High_loss$Strt[inx - 1]

DPM_356_out_High_loss
#        symbol     Strt      End  len Overlap len_no_overlap
#121    TPTE2P4 26508213 26579690 1605  153795           1605
#46     CYCSP49 26549425 26549743  319  -30265          41530
#116 SLC25A15P1 26586642 26591601  342   36899            342
#84     PARP4P1 26594851 26634652 2337    3250           2337
```

**Data.**

```
DPM_356_out_High_loss <- read.table(text = "
    symbol  Strt    End len Overlap
121 TPTE2P4 26508213    26579690    1605    153795
46  CYCSP49 26549425    26549743    319 -30265
116 SLC25A15P1  26586642    26591601    342 36899
84  PARP4P1 26594851    26634652    2337    3250
", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution:

```
DPM_356_out_High_loss %>% mutate(no_overlap_len = if_else(Overlap<0, End-lag(Strt), len))
# A tibble: 4 x 6
  symbol         Strt      End   len Overlap no_overlap_len
  <chr>         <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>          <dbl>
1 TPTE2P4    26508213 26579690  1605  153795           1605
2 CYCSP49    26549425 26549743   319  -30265          41530
3 SLC25A15P1 26586642 26591601   342   36899            342
4 PARP4P1    26594851 26634652  2337    3250           2337
```

Comment: Please accept this answer if it works for you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers